# how can I get user country phonenumber code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how can I get user country phonenumber code? for example for USA its `+1`

below code gets the country name / code but not the phonenumber code

```
 System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the phone number country code for a country? or how to get it from a phone number? Or something else? Not every users phone number will be registered in the same country that they selected in the "regional and language options" section of the control panel...

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103113/getting-country-calling-code-in-net-framework.  It looks like you are on your own here

Comment: `phonenumber code` thanks ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

end up using `libphonenumber-csharp` plugin. seem to be working fine